# Adding 2 series containing mix of string, integer and 0

Tags: python, series, addition, typeconverter

I have a df called `production`. For certain dates (meaning for certain columns in `production`) I want to add 2 values (datatype: Series) of the same column as following:

```
for date in production.iloc[1, 2:]:
    production.loc[15, production.iloc[1]==date] = production.loc[13, production.iloc[1]==date] + production.loc[14, production.iloc[1]==date]
```

Let's simplify the calculation to A=B+C.

Then B and C each contain one value but are of datatype Series and they can each have the following values:

- It can be left empty by the user. In that case I will find it as a string `''`.
- It can be registered as 0 (I think this will reach me as a string as well `'0.0'`.
- It can be registerd as a postive number (I think this will reach me as a string as well).

What I would like to see is that A will look empty if neither B nor C is positive. Meaning A should look empty (either nan or `''`) if both B and C are either `''` or `'0.0'`.

My question is how can I do this in an efficient way? If both B and C are empty then it adds up the 2 strings and will stay empty. But when a number is entered, I need to convert to int. The program won't let me convert to int because most times the registered value is an empty string `''`. And then if for example I have to add 0 to 0, then how will I get the field to look empty again?

Is there a more efficient way then splitting it up in a lot of different scenarios, converting each one separately adding `.values[0]` after B and C (because they are Series), then doing the addition and then replacing it back to '' in case A becomes 0?

Thank you!